# Delphi 11.2, IOS, and Dark mode

Tags: ios, delphi

In my IOS app, I have some components that use custom styles. When run in IOS's Light mode, the components appear correctly. However, when run under Dark mode on the IOS device, the colors of the "text" properties of the custom styles are not being "flipped".

The text properties of those styles are using the `TText` and `TActiveStyleTextObject` components. The custom styles are either for the `TTreeViewItem` or `TListBoxItem` components, but not sure if the problem is limited to those components only, as I do not use custom styles for other components.

All the the text properties for the custom styles use the same colors as the default styles. I did add a "IOS13 Dark" style to the Style book and flipped the colors within the style hoping that was the problem. But I have confirmed that the app is using the `IOS` styles regardless of the Light/Dark mode, and not the `IOS13 Dark` styles.

So it appears the Delphi logic is not flipping any text colors for styles set up in a Style Book when switching between the IOS's Light and Dark modes.

Anyone else seen this problem and had success in fixing it?